# Can I format the text in a div according to a pattern with a css rule?

Tags: javascript, css, html, css-selectors

I have a table like this:

[image: Table with the column I want to format]

I want to format the circled text so that all the words before the colons (":") are bold, like this:

**PARAMETER1**: something; **PARAMETER2**: something else, etc.

Is there a CSS selector that can accomplish that?

Comment: CSS doesn't read content. Can you add your code?

Comment: Can you use javascript? Also, can you copy that piece of text into your question?

Comment: Are you able to change the html?  If you could put those parameters in `<span>` tags and give them a class, you could target that class in css and make them bold.

Comment: I use struts, the column is generated dinamically thank's to tag "Display column" but i can wrap content in some element like div ecc if i want, but  i dont'know what tag will display until page is charged

Comment: Ye i can wrap into span content, but i need bold only first word before ":" not all

Comment: Yeas, thats what I mean.  ONLY wrap the parameters in the span tag, not the whole block of text.  Wherever that text is coming from.   Aside from that, I'm sorry to say you're out of luck.  You could use possibly regex and javascript though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it inside a td:

```
<p>
<span>Parameter:</span>
<span>Value</span>
</p>
```

And then in css, you can use first-child as:

```
p > span:first-child{
font-weight:bold;
}
```

Or, you can simply use 1 span,

```
<p>
<span>Parameter:</span>
Value
</p>
```

And CSS as:

```
p > span{
font-weight:bold;
}
```